# how did the authors of the AKS-Paper come up with the upper bound for r? and what does the multiplicative order have to do with anything?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, number-theory, primes

I have been recently reading the paper "PRIMES is in P", but unfortunately a lot the steps were skipped, which led to confusion. My main problem is with the upper bound on r which was not explained at all in the paper(i don't see the connection of these bounds to the runtime of the algorithm), for example how did they come up with the upper bound O(log^5 n) for r, why is it exactly this number? why not O(log^2 n) or something else. Moreover they had set a condition for r in the second step of the algorithm. They wanted the order of r mod n to be greater than log^2 n, but i don't see why this has anything to do with polynomial runtime or why does it have to be greater than log^2 n.

Can anyone please explain why this is true? or how to derive these numbers?

Comment: This version of the paper might be more useful, maybe: https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf

Comment: The simple answer is, these conditions make the proof work. You'll have to carefully read the proof to see where all of them come in.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, yeah but that is exactly my question why these numbers? i mean could have bounded r with any other logarithm and the algorithm would still run in polynomial time. I did read the paper(including the last version) but i fail to see where the numbers come from. They simply say: we have to  bound r to get polynomial runtime. And that is okay and logical, but they don't really say how did they come up with these bounds.

Comment: Again, it's likely what was needed to make the proof work.  It's not enough for the algorithm to run in polynomial time; it also has to be provably correct.  It's not enough to read the paper and hope they'll explicitly state the answer -- you need to work through the proof and see where they are using the fact that the numbers are in that range, and then think through what would happen to the proof if they weren't.